# Stability of a 10km planetoid with a micro-black hole in its centre

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, geophysics

Let's assume there is a tiny, 10km-radius planetoid with a micro-black hole in its centre of about 10^19kg, so the surface of the planetoid is at 1g. How it appeared (or was constructed) would be the scope of another question, and is out of the scope of this one. The planetoid itself has remained undisturbed for a very long time, to avoid it having an effect on its present state. To keep things simple, let's assume an initial composition similar to early Earth.

What would such a planetoid look like? How fast (or slow) could it rotate? Would it have a molten core like a planet, or a uniform interior, like an asteroid? Would it be stable in the first place?

Comment: A BH of that mass has a Schwarzschild radius around 15 nm. Do we assume the BH emits Hawking radiation? If so, its temperature is around 12000 K, but the luminosity is tiny. See https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator

Comment: @PM2Ring If the Hawking radiation has non-negligible effects, it would be best to account for it, though I am not certain it would have a big impact.

Comment: With a luminosity of only 3.56 microwatts, I assume that most of the heat will be radiated away, rather than making a measurable increase in the temperature of the planetoid, except very close to the BH. OTOH, at the atomic scale, that's pretty powerful: 22 TeV per second, so it will tend to repel atoms & electrons that are falling towards the BH.